# What is javascript event delegation and how to keep my js DRY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dry

My case

```
$(".myElementWithSpecialActionHandler").click(function(){});
```

after the element was relocated, say insert to a different position of the page,

```
var content_from_table = from_table_obj.html(); 
var content_target_table = to_table_obj.html();
```

before the ajax call. And I put

```
from_table_obj.html(content_target_table); 
to_table_obj.html(content_from_table);" in the ajax response handler.
```

after that the event handler function stops working. So I have to do

```
// after DOM manipulation
// again >.<
$(".myElementWithSpecialActionHandler").click(function(){});
```

Is [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) the only to solve this? Or are there better way to avoid the scenario at the first place?

**EDIT** : added "relocate" code

Comment: what do you mean by *element was relocated*?

Comment: How do you 'relocate' element? Using any relevant method as append() or prepend() (which move element when already existing), handlers are keept. So post relevant code you are using for moving element

Comment: if the `to_table_obj` element is static then event delegation is the way to go like `to_table_obj.on('click', '.myElementWithSpecialActionHandler', function(){})`

Comment: @ArunPJohny What do you mean by "static"? In my case, there would be a lot of "tables" being added in and removed on the fly. And I need to bind events handlers to all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is deleting the element and creating it again (Don't know why). So it no longer is the same element and your event handler won't work.

In this case, yes, you should use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', ".myElementWithSpecialActionHandler", function(){});
```

**EDIT:**

You can use .appendTo() to add it to another place (maybe a hidden div or something). Or you could just appendTo() it to its destination but hide it until you ajax callback fires. I created a little jsfiddle to show you that appendTo() does not remove the event handler: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eM7eR/)

```
var divId = '#div2';
$('button').on('click', function() {
   $(this).appendTo(divId);
    divId = divId == '#div2' ? '#div1' : '#div2';
});
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi. My intention is to only "relocate" in this case. How can I achieve this without "deleting the element and creating it " ??

Comment: @n by adding it to some other place? And by "it", I mean the element, not its HTML.